# Operation Count of this Loop

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, nested-loops

```
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < n; i *= 2) {
    for (int j = n; j > 0; j /= 2) {
        for (int k = j; k < n; k += 2) {
            sum += i + j * k;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to calculate the operation count of the above given nested loop. The first and second loop variable is independent.

My try:

```
10n(logn)^2 + 1
```

How do I calculate it correctly? The most inner loop is the main problem.

Answer (score 1):

Methodically, you may proceed using Sigma notation:

[image]

[image]

[image]